# JavaScript Alert Box Popup Issue

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I am having an issue with an Alert Box not appearing on the screen after I click a submit button. I have searched this forum and online for answers and I don't see what is wrong with my code. As with most of my issues, the solution is probably a simple fix but I can't seem to find the issue after going through my code. Any help is appreciated.

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stopClock() {
        clearInterval (clockId);
        correctAns = gradeQuiz();
        alert('You have' + correctAns + 'correct of 5 in' + timer + 'seconds');
    }  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function runClock() {
        seconds++;
        document.getElementById('quizclock').value=seconds;
    }   
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function startClock() {
        showQuiz();
        clockId=setInterval ("runClock()", 1000);
    }
</script>

function resetQuiz() {
    document.quiz.quizclock.value = 0;
    for (i=0; i<document.quiz.elements.length; i++)document.quiz.elements[i].disabled=false;  
    document.quiz.stop.disabled = true;
}

function showQuiz() {
    document.getElementById("quiztable").style.visibility="visible";
    document.quiz.start.disabled = true;
    document.quiz.stop.disabled = false;
}

function hideQuiz() {
    document.getElementById("quiztable").style.visibility="hidden";
}

function gradeQuiz() {
    correct=0;
    if (document.quiz.q1[1].checked) correct++;
    if (document.quiz.q2[3].checked) correct++;
    if (document.quiz.q3[0].checked) correct++;
    if (document.quiz.q4[3].checked) correct++;
    if (document.quiz.q5[2].checked) correct++;

    document.getElementById("cor1").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    document.getElementById("cor2").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    document.getElementById("cor3").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    document.getElementById("cor4").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    document.getElementById("cor5").style.backgroundColor="yellow";

    for (i=0; i<document.quiz.elements.length; i++)document.quiz.elements[i].disabled=true;  

    return correct;
}
```

html for button that pops up the alert

```
<input id="stop" type="button" value="Submit Answers" onclick="stopClock()"/>
```

Comment: so, what is your issue?

Comment: Is the problem that the pop up is appearing and you don't want it to? Or that it isn't appearing at all?

Comment: The alert box won't show up when the Submit Button is clicked.

Comment: you have an error in your javascript, so execution never reaches `alert`

Comment: what is the `clockId` and `gradeQuiz` function and the `timer`?

Comment: delete a space between clearInterval and (clockId).

Comment: @БогданГусейнов - or insert more spaces - it will have the same effect

Comment: there is 3 possible issues : 1)clockId is not defined; 2) correctAns is not defined; 3) gradeQuiz is not defined

Comment: You have more then one issue and without sharing all your functions, we will not be able to help.

Comment: I have added the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your variables and use `seconds` in `alert`.

Change your functions to:

```
var clockId;
var seconds = 0;
function stopClock() {
  clearInterval (clockId);
  correctAns = gradeQuiz();
  alert('You have' + correctAns + 'correct of 5 in' + seconds + 'seconds');
}  

function startClock() {
  showQuiz();
  seconds = 0;
  clockId=setInterval (runClock, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple. I am glad this community is detail oriented. Thanks Igor.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have a variable undefined, check this working demo

```
function gradeQuiz() {
  return 'something';
}

var clockId, i = timer = 0;

clockId = setInterval(function() {
  i++;

  $('h2').text(i);

}, 200);


function stopClock() {
  clearInterval (clockId);
  correctAns = gradeQuiz();

  alert('You have ' + correctAns + ' correct of 5 in  ' + timer + ' seconds');
}


$('button').on('click', stopClock);
```

http://jsbin.com/toyibekivu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

If you remove

```
alert('You have' + correctAns + 'correct of 5 in' + timer + 'seconds');
```

from your `stopClock()` function no alert will appear on the screen.

Comment: excellent! no `alert` - no "having an issue with an Alert Box appearing on the screen".

Comment: i dont believe this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: of course not. But the quality of this answer matches perfectly the quality of the question.

Comment: I was going off the first line of the question 'I am having an issue with an Alert Box appearing **on** the screen **after** I click a submit button'

Comment: Nobody should be answering this question, at this point they are all just guesses.